# netbeans remote debugger out of sync

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am trying to use NetBeans 8.0.2 on win7 to debug a java web app on a remote Linux server.  The source code is developed on win7 and committed to subversion.  On the Linux server I checkout the code from svn and build with maven after first doing a clean.  I deploy the .war file to a glassfish server and then attach the debugger and set a breakpoint in NB.  I run the web app in Firefox and the debugger stops properly at the breakpoint.  Then I "step into" F7 the code but it jumps to a location that is off by about 4 lines of where it is supposed to hit.  After that it starts jumping off to even stranger locations and the code I want to study never gets hit.  I have made sure the source code on both wind7 and Linux are the same.  Any ideas why it seems to be out of sync?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the same but older class was located in a jar file in the glassfish startup library.  That's why it didn't show up when I searched for the class name.  This web app uses a custom realm and hence needed the class earlier during glassfish initialization.  Man I hate inheriting difficult stuff like this with no documentation!